# MySql Sum with Case query to output another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table table1 like this.

```
    +---------+-------+
    | name    | Value | 
    +---------+-------+
    |       a | 1     | 
    |       b | 3     |
    |       a | 1     |
    |       d | 4     |
    |       c | 4     |
    |       d | 2     |
    +---------+-------+
```

I need to create another table which has a distinct name and the sum of values which whose names are the same from the previous table like this..

```
+---------+-------+
| name    | Value | 
+---------+-------+
|       a | 2     | 
|       b | 3     |
|       c | 4     |
|       d | 6     |
+---------+-------+
```

I have tried the query

```
SELECT Distinct t1.name, SUM (Case when t1.Name = t2.Name then t1.Value end) 
from table1 t1 join table1 t2
```

which doesn't seem to work.

I am building a desktop application using c# to access these values in the output table, and I can easily obtain the desired result by simply using linq as opposed to the server side queries. Is it good practice to have the desktop application achieve this instead of creating the table in the database?

Comment: use group by and try

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try

```
select name, sum(Value)
from yourtable
group by name
```

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e283/2)**